# How to render the original size of a texture easily?

Tags: c++, sdl-2

What I mean is, do I have to create a `SDL_Rect` for every texture I want to render, or does `SDL_Texture` have a `SDL_Rect` member I can pass to

```
    int SDL_RenderCopy(SDL_Renderer*   renderer,
                       SDL_Texture*    texture,
                       const SDL_Rect* srcrect,
                       const SDL_Rect* dstrect)
```

as its `dstrect`.

I looked for documentation about what's inside `SDL_Texture`, but I can't find any.

Comment: SDL is open source, why not just open up the file containing the definition of `SDL_Texture` and look at what it contains?

Comment: You can have a look at this : https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_QueryTexture?highlight=%28\bCategoryAPI\b%29|%28SDLFunctionTemplate%29h
It will give you the width and height. But you would have to create an `SDL_Rect` from these.

Comment: @Captain Obvlious I tried that too. I found SDL_Rect but not SDL_Texture :/

Edit: I'm not saying it isn't there, just that I suck at finding. I only found it's declaration and `typedef`

Comment: @olevegard Well, it's the next best thing. I can create a function that returns a SDL_Rect. Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest that you create a `struct` that contains both a `SDL_Texture` and `SDL_Rect` though. Will make everything a lot easier.

Answer (score 2):

To get the width and height of the texture you can use [SDL_QueryTexture](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_QueryTexture) and create the SDL_Rect using that.